# confused about dynamic methods

Tags: python, dynamic

I am trying to understand how to create objects, that have methods, which are defined by a list of strings. I do not know, how it is called that I am trying to do, so searching is pretty difficult for me at the moment. I was looking into closures a bit, and had a look at decorators and descriptors and now I am very confused.

I was able to boil down my problem into ~20 lines of code below. So I am defining this `Dyn` class, which will end up having methods according to the names, given in the `__init__` call. It works, but for some reason the methods turn out to be all **doing the same**

```
import types

class Dyn(object):

    def __init__(self, things=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
        for t in things:
            def method(self, number):
                print number*t
            setattr(self, t, types.MethodType(method, self))
```

When I try this, e.g. like so:

```
first = Dyn()
first.foo(3)
first.bar(1)
```

the result is:

```
bazbazbaz
baz
```

and not:

```
foofoofoo
bar
```

as I expected.

Can anyone give me a push into the right direction?

Comment: Based on `things`, you should also read http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761